# Test Credentials to access a web page

Tags: c#, asmx, xmlhttprequest, credentials

Is there a nice and tested piece of code out there that I can use for this purpose:

get the user/pass and the address of a web service (asmx page) and check if the user/pass are valid or not.

I think I should use HTTPRequest,etc to do that but I do not have a good knowledge on that topic , causing my current method to not working properly.

If there is a good piece of code for this purpose I appreciate for pointing me to that.

Thanks

P.S: I am not using DefaultCredentials in my code. Since I want them to enter user/pass so now I need to be able to TEST their user/pass and show proper message to them if their credentials is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HttpWebRequest.Credentials Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials?view=net-7.0) (depends on the web service authentication) and the [CredentialCache Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache?view=net-7.0).

Also some code examples (from google):
[Retrieving HTTP content in .NET](https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebrequest/dotnetwebrequest.htm)
Combine [Invoking Web Service dynamically using HttpWebRequest](https://web.archive.org/web/20201021135807/http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/03/26/109886.aspx) with `.Credentials`.

Comment: yeah Thanks, I saw that page you had posted but in its example it is doing this:  " request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; "  which is Not what I need. I need to "Test" the user/pass that users have entered.

Comment: Use your own instance of `CredentialCache` instead (added a link so you see how).

Comment: I do not have problem with "setting" my credentials. Just I want a simple method that does this: gets a user name, a password, a asmx page addresss and determines if this user/pass is correct or not. That's it and I do not see it anywhere in the pages you posted. Thanks tho.

Comment: What's the problem? Create a form or a console application. A `TextBox` and `Button` or `Console.ReadLine();` to get input from the user and pass it to the code using `CredentialCache` for credentials (username, password) and `HttpWebRequest` with the URL you got from user... What more do you need? If it returns OK, you can access the service, if not, you get a 401 status code back => not able to login...

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool TestCredentials(string url, string username, string password)
{
    var web = new WebClient();
    web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);

    try
    {   
        web.DownloadData(url);
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        throw;
    }   
}
```